# Magento 2 Overide CMS Helper

Tags: magento2, blocks, pdf, wysiwyg, upload

I tried to override the Image helper on CMS block for uploading pdf files. 
Now i added the pdf files but i need to link for pdf file instead of img tag. And also i tried to override the CMS Image insert selection. but not able to override.

In di.xml,

```
<preference for="Magento\Cms\Helper\Wysiwyg" type="MyCompany\Name\Helper\Wysiwyg" />
```

Override Image helper file

```
  namespace Hexamarvel\Pdfupload\Helper\Wysiwyg;  
class Images extends \Magento\Cms\Helper\Wysiwyg\Images {
    public function getImageHtmlDeclaration($filename, $renderAsTag = false){
         $fileurl = $this->getCurrentUrl() . $filename;
            $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
            $mediaPath = str_replace($mediaUrl, '', $fileurl);
            $directive = sprintf('{{media url="%s"}}', $mediaPath);
            if ($renderAsTag) {
                $html = sprintf('<img src="%s" alt="" />', $this->isUsingStaticUrlsAllowed() ? $fileurl : $directive);
            } else {
                if ($this->isUsingStaticUrlsAllowed()) {
                    $html = $fileurl; // $mediaPath;
                } else {
                    $directive = $this->urlEncoder->encode($directive);

                    $html = $this->_backendData->getUrl(
                        'cms/wysiwyg/directive',
                        [
                            '___directive' => $directive,
                            '_escape_params' => false,
                        ]
                    );
                }
            }
            return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: which magento version you have using?

Comment: Magento  version is 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with Magento 2. It does not support PDF.

Preference issue

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9850

https://github.com/magento/up-for-grabs/issues/2

But on 
https://github.com/magento/up-for-grabs/issues/2 , have a solution which may help you;

Solution is given by [Sarbjeet Singh](https://github.com/sarbjeet-cmsDev/) that might help you.

https://github.com/sarbjeet-cmsDev/magento2_editorpdf